# Chromium Browser Singleton Bug caused by power failure

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

A power failure resulted in the following bug of Chromium Browser on Ubuntu -

[12489:12489:0811/114557:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(264)] Failed to create /home/user01/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: File exists
[12489:12489:0811/114557:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1155)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the file?

You could also run chrome with --user-data-dir=/home/user01/.config/*some-other-dir* to run with a fresh profile in a new location.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and found a fix. In my case the problem was that my root partition was out of space. I found 100 GB of files to delete and chromium worked again instantly.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just ran into this same problem and never would have even thought my disk was full. It shouldn't have been but apparently flatpak was running amok with it's cache folders. So you actually solved 2 problems for me 

Answer (score 1):

Just delete file '/home/user01/.config/chromium/SingletonLock', chrome will works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helps me.